# How to I view email using gmail API within a server environment? (Python)

Tags: gmail-api

I want to be able to retrieve emails from a gmail inbox but I cant find a way to properly authenticate in a server environment. Traditional authentication uses this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 however I don't have access to a web browser with javascript within a server environment so I cant authenticate. A service account wont work because I wont be able to access inbox of my main email address through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is to create the authentication tokens on computer then use a shell script to automate the transfer of the files over ssh onto the server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permission to temporarily open a port on the server, then you can use the built-in authentication server:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secret_file, scopes)
cred = flow.run_local_server(open_browser=False, port=port)
```

By setting `open_browser` to `False` the script is going to print the url to the command line, you can then open the link locally in your web browser and after the successful authentication you Google is going to redirect you with your token to the websever running on your server. You can see this functionality in action in a script I use to [sort my email using machine learning](https://github.com/jan-janssen/pygmailsorter).